# openpyxl - read third row from input file

Tags: python, openpyxl

The input file format is changed. 
origin input file

```
   A      B      C
1 Tom    Red    True
2 Tom    Red    False
3 Marry  Green  False
4 Marry  Green  True
5 Babara Red    False
```

changed input file

```
   A      B      C
1 Title
2 Name  Color  Result 
3 Tom    Red    True
4 Tom    Red    False
5 Marry  Green  False
6 Marry  Green  True
7 Babara Red    False
```

Now, I'd like to read from 3rd row of the input file.

How can I modify the code below ?

```
import collections
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1['test']
a_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in ws1.rows:
    a_dict[row[0].value+','+row[1].value].append(str(row[2].value))

wb2 = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws2 = wb2.create_sheet()
for key,value in a_dict.items():
    temp = key.split(',')
    temp.append(','.join(value))
    ws2.append(temp)
wb2.save('new_test.xlsx')
```

The output file is below

```
   A      B        Result
1 Tom    Red    True,False
2 Marry  Green  False,True
3 Babara Red    False
```

Answer (score 1):

Access any element of a collection by `n-1` where `n` is the position in the list(since we start counting in lists from 0). If `ws_in.rows` is a generator you will have to cast it as a list, so do `list(ws_in.rows)[2]` to access the third row.

Comment: So I tried `for row in list(ws_in.rows)[2] :
        a_dict[row[1].value+','+row[2].value].append(str(row[6].value))`

Comment: and the Error :  `a_dict[row[1].value+','+row[2].value].append(str(row[6].value))
TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support indexing`

Comment: OK, so it sounds like ws_in.rows is a list of lists of `Cell` objects. So calling an index on it isn't going to work. Remove the `[1]`, `[2]` and `[6]` from the line.

Comment: well.. I use `a_dict.item' after the code. so I can't remove [1],[2],[6]

Comment: But you're no longer iterating through the rows, so it doesn't make sense to do it this way. You're iterating through the columns in the third row.

Comment: Great. Sorry I couldn't help any further, I had gone to bed.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the rows you want to read using `ws.iter_rows()` If you want to read from the third row simply set `min_row=3`.